# create object from existing one using Object.create()

Tags: javascript, object

hey after looking in mdn [Object.create() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
Im trying to duplicate their example but it doesnt work

here is what I tried and what I got

```js
    const oTest = {a:1,b:2}
 
    const test1 = Object.create(oTest)
 
    console.log(oTest)  //{a: 1, b: 2}
    console.log(test1 ) //{}
```

I expected test1 to console `{a: 1, b: 2}`

Comment: What does `console.log(test1.a)` output?

Comment: I think it doesn't copy the object, but just creates a new Object prototype. if you log `test1.a` you should get `1`

Comment: @OlivierKrull, "The Object.create() method creates a new object, using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created object."

Comment: @Mulperi it's kind of what I tried to say ;-)

Comment: `console.log(test1.__proto__)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Object.Create() doing under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116846/what-is-object-create-doing-under-the-hood)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said, the existing object is used as the prototype for the new created object. So you do not see it in a console.log (at least in Node). Try it in chrome and will this that the `__proto__` has your oTest object. [image]

If you want to copy the object properties in your new object you can `const test2 = {...oTest}`. It is the spread operator : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create(o)` creates an empty object. Sure, one that inherits properties from `o`, but that just means they are available on access and don't actually get copied into own properties. Your console only shows the own properties - but if you expand the object, it should also show the prototype chain.

```
const oTest = {a:1,b:2};
const test1 = Object.create(oTest);

console.log(oTest) // {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(test1) // {}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(test1) == oTest) // true
console.log(test1.a) // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check it with Chrome Developer tools for example, you can see the prototype of the object and it's properties.

Or you can just `console.log(test1.__proto__)` to view those that way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use Object.assign() to create a copy of existing object.

const oTest = {a:1,b:2}

const test1 = Object.assign(oTest)

console.log(oTest)  //{a: 1, b: 2}

console.log(test1) //{a: 1, b: 2}